# Exporting data of a 3d Plot

Tags: plotting, export

I have plotted a 3d-plot. But I need its data. I mean I need to export data of this plot in a text file 
(as

x y z

x y z

x y z ).

Can anyone help me? In the following, I type my code.

```
\[Theta]0 = 30*Pi/180;
Aw = -10;
Bw = 0.5;
Cw = 20;
max = 0.6;
H[\[Rho]_, \[Theta]_] := 
Aw/\[Rho] + Bw/\[Rho]^2 + Cw*(\[Theta] - \[Theta]0)^2;
Plot3D[H[\[Rho], \[Theta]] /. {\[Rho] -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], \[Theta] -> 
ArcTan[x, y]}, {x, 0.01, max}, {y, 0.01, max}]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with having an equidistant x-y-grid, then it's probably not worth going through the trouble of extracting the data from the plot. You can use `Table` to achieve this:

```
θ0 = 30*Pi/180;
Aw = -10;
Bw = 0.5;
Cw = 20;
max = 0.6;
H[ρ_, θ_] := Aw/ρ + Bw/ρ^2 + Cw*(θ - θ0)^2;

n = 100;
data = Table[{x, y, 
    H[ρ, θ] /. {ρ -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ -> 
       ArcTan[x, y]}}, {x, 0.01, max, (max - 0.01)/(n - 1)}, {y, 0.01,
     max, (max - 0.01)/(n - 1)}];

Export["tmp/data.dat", data, "Table"]
```

This gives you 100x100 `{x,y,z}` values exported in a text file.

### Edit

To get the format you want, you need to flatten the matrix of `{x,y,z}` values to a list of `{x,y,z}` values. Then you can export it as "TSV" which is tab-separated values

```
Export["tmp/data.dat", Flatten[data, 1], "TSV"]
```

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you, dear halirutan

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer your question without knowledge about the grid is as follows:

Give your Plot a name

```
bild = Plot3D[H[\[Rho], \[Theta]] /. {\[Rho] -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], \[Theta] ->ArcTan[x, y]}, {x, 0.01, max}, {y, 0.01, max}, Mesh -> All,AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

and extract the plotted points

```
pts = Cases[bild, GraphicsComplex[a_, ___] :> a, Infinity] [[1]] (*{x,y,z}*)

Export["xyz.dat",pts]
```

save the points.